# Howto get the Value of an Selected Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, select

How Can i get the value of an Selected object like select Id="foo" there are many options how can i get the value of the current selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The currently selected option in a `<select>` can be retrieved by inspecting the **value** attribute:

Using jQuery:

```
$("#foo").val()
```

Without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("foo").value
```

Comment: `value` is a property, not an attribute. I blame jQuery for creating this muddle in people's minds with its ill-named `attr()` method.

Answer (score 4):

The surest way for cross-browser support is

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
var val = foo.options[foo.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('foo').value
```

Comment: sorry, Philippe answered while I was answering